# Get Image path and store In SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, image, sqlite

I am trying to get the path of the image the user selects from the gallery. So far I have made the button and used the following code to get the user to select the image from gallery:

```
public void image(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to get the path of this image so that I can store it in the database to be used to retrieve it later. I know how to insert the path into the DB but just don't know how to get the path name.

Also, I want to copy the image the user has selected and paste into a new folder, where all the images will be.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So far I have made the button and used the following code to get the user to select the image from gallery

No, you are asking the user to select an image. Any number of apps can offer an activity that supports `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for `image/*` data, not just something that you consider to be a gallery.

> Now, I'm trying to get the path of this image so that I can store it in the database to be used to retrieve it later

There is no path, and there is nothing that you can store that you can necessarily use later. The `Uri` that you get back (via the `Intent` passed into `onActivityResult()`) will work for a short time. It is reminiscent of a URL you might get to an image in a Web site, where the URL only works while the user is authenticated. Either use the `Uri` right away, or plan on having the user pick the image again in the future. Or, switch to the [Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) and hope that you get a `Uri` that is durable and has persistable permissions (and set your `minSdkVersion` to 19 or higher).

> I want to copy the image the user has selected and paste into a new folder, where all the images will be

It is unclear what "copy the image the user has selected and paste into a new folder" means to you. If you mean what computer users would refer to as "copy the file", [use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29) to get an `InputStream` on the image. Then, use standard Java I/O to copy that to some file under your control. The path to *that* file you could store in your database, as you are now managing that copy of the file. However, this causes duplication of data (two copies of the image), which the user may or may not want.

Answer (score 0):

You can store image in bytearray format in sqlite database.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);

byte[] byteArray=baos.toByteArray();
```

and then use this byteArray to insert image in Sqlite. :)

Hope this helps to you.